# Сочетание "и хотя если"

Tags: пунктуация

И хотя если - возможно ли такое сочетание союзов? "И хотя, и если" - видел, "хотя если" - тоже видел. А вот если все вместе - "и хотя если"? Как объяснить тогда постановку союзов? Думал и составил такой пример:

Сергей не видел Юлю всего три года, и() хотя() если он и встретится с ней сейчас лицом к лицу, она его не узнает.

По логике здесь в обоих случаях нужна запятая.

Answer (score 2):

Такое сочетание **невозможно**. Рядом могут быть союзы *и хотя*,  *и если*,  *хотя если*. Ваш пример, к сожалению,  неудачен. Один союз явно лишний. Возможные варианты вашего предложения (в первых двух вариантах слово *всего* по смыслу лучше заменить на *уже*, или *целых*, или *долгих*):

1. Сергей не видел Юлю **уже** три года, и, хотя он и встретится с ней сейчас лицом к лицу, она его не узнает.
2. Сергей не видел Юлю  **долгих** три года, и, если он и встретится с ней сейчас лицом к лицу, она его не узнает.
3. Сергей не видел Юлю всего три года, хотя, если он и встретится с ней сейчас лицом к лицу, она его не узнает.

Comment: Ну а почему в третьем примере не может быть "И" пере всей этой "хотя если" конструкцией?

Comment: Так нарушится логика: в первых двух примерах (долго не видел) "и" по смыслу эквивалентно словам "так что" или "поэтому" (не узнает), что не проходит в третьем примере (всего три года).

Answer (score 1):

Cтечение союзов **и**+**хотя**+**если** организовать можно, но мне не совсем понятен по логическим связям ваш пример, поэтому приведу свой.

> Не всегда наши желания совпадают с нашими возможностями, **и, хотя, если**
>
> погода хорошая, можно пойти погулять, иногда хочется побыть дома или
>
> приходится идти на работу.

Запятые перед "хотя" и "если" нужны, поскольку нет второй части составного союза типа "хотя... но" или "если... то", и в результате имеет место "изымаемость оборота с сохранением общего смысла", по Розенталю (можно изъять "если погода хорошая" или целиком "хотя... можно пойти погулять").

Comment: И в самом деле можно. Отлично!

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос не вызывает серьезного к себе отношения, но фразу такую вполне можно построить.

> Аня знала Борю со школы, и хотя, если спросить сейчас, вряд ли
>   вспомнит его, но попробовать можно.

Здесь, правда, "хотя ..., но".